# NavigationView overlaps content

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigationview

I have an application in which I'm trying to add a `NavigationView`. I've done this:

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.testnavigation2.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_profiles" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_profiles.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/register_background"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="No items in profiles database." />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_users"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/gray_back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:text="Add profile"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView_users"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pull_down_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my **nav_header_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I load my application, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, my button is being cut by the **nav_header**, but I have no idea why.

Can anybody help me with this?
**EDIT:**

When I add modifications suggested by @Abhilash, now it looks like this:

[image]

And everything is moved down that space. What I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: all my styles are FULL SCREEN! Dunno it that's interesting to know...

Comment: can you put your appbar layout and <include> layout under RelativeLayout in app_bar_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add scrolling behavior to your content relative layout ..

Ex:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/register_background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_NoProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="No items in profiles database."
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_users"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_NoProfile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/gray_back"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView_users"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Add profile"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pull_down_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works partially... Now it moves all so much down... (NOTE: I have my app in fullscreen mode). See my edit to see how it looks now!

Comment: any idea on why my screen is looking more down than expected?

Comment: try removing android:layout_gravity="center" from your relative layout